# Doxygen document C functions in Objective-C projects

Tags: objective-c, documentation, doxygen

I am programming a project in Objective-C and I have started to use Doxygen to automatically generate documentation. A significant portion of the project contains basic C functions. Unfortunately Doxygen is not documenting C functions, only Objective-C classes and their methods. I have the functions defined in several header files like so:

```
BOOL myFunc(void);
```

Which I then have implemented in a .m.

Does Doxygen not detect straight C functions in Objective-C or is there an option I have to turn on? Is my function defined incorrectly for Doxygen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxygen certainly documents straight C functions.

**After more testing**

Use the Doxywizard and check the values in expert mode - it provides some nice help when you mouse over things. In particular, you should have changed the default so EXTRACT_ALL is
**checked**

I think needing this to be set, opposite to the default, is possibly a bug.

If desperate, post the settings up in the question. I just created a sample from scratch and verified that your function showed up using Doxygen when I use EXTRACT_ALL but there is no File Members section if I turn that off.

You should see the functions underneath Files - File Members, as [seen here](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/globals_func.html) in the VTK docs.

Sorry I didn't pick it up earlier but I always have EXTRACT_ALL on as I'm working on legacy code bases where most functions lack special comments.

**earlier idea** Try adding an @file comment at the top of the file to see if that is being processed.

```
   /// @file fred.h This file defines functions used in fred.m
```

My bet is that your file extension or your directory is not included in the doxygen setup file you're running.

Comment: Nope its definitley getting processed. The files are listed in it. And I tried your @file thing no help. When running under Objective C does it stick to just methods and avoid c functions?

Comment: Ok that worked better it is now listing all of them which is great, but it is still not documenting them with the comments.

Comment: NVM I fixed it thank you so much! (I will you give you the bounty as soon as I can)

Comment: I found that setting EXTRACT_ALL did not fix it for me BUT, setting `SHOW_FILES = YES` fixes it.